# "Show more", google, anchors and Ajax

Tags: ajax, anchor

I'd like a "show more" facility to replace a navigation bar. Basically, each time a user hits the "show more" button, new comments are shown.

Something like :

```
<div id='comment1'>...</div>
...
<div id='comment5'>...</div>
<input...>Show more</input>
```

Show more will activate some AJAX to get the next 5 comments.

A **noscript** will return all the comments for google.

But if a google indexes comment6 which is not shown by default, how can I know that I need to show at least 10 records (each show more displays 5 records) ?

I want this to work in the context of http://mysite.com/#comment6

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript-code
`var regex = "#.+$";

    var myregex = new RegExp(regex);

    var match = myregex.exec(window.location.href);

    if (match == null) {

        alert("no anchors");

    } else {

        alert(match); 
    }`
(found here: http://www.ajax-community.de/javascript/4219-anker-js-auslesen.html#post20803) is able to return "#comment6" in your example. You should be able to use this value to find out how many records you have to show.

**Edit**
Oops, I sould have read the whole thread... There is a better solution:

```
alert(document.location.hash) //returns the current anchor
alert(document.location.hash.substr(1)) // returns the current anchor without "#"
```

(Source: http://www.ajax-community.de/javascript/4219-anker-js-auslesen.html#post20804)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no idea I could check for the hash part of an URL in javascript.